# Python list not converting into a integer

Tags: python

Hi I'm trying to convert my file back into a integer, the file reads numbers but is stored in a string and I'm trying to convert it into a integer the error I keep getting is:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

My code:

```
with open('Position_of_Words.txt') as d:    #my file 
    for line in d:
        print (int(line)) #Trying to convert into a integer


position_of_words_list = line.split(" ")  #make into list
print (position_of_words_list)
```

Comment: How does your file look like?

Comment: your code is weird, read the file before processing it. `data = d.read()`

Comment: 1 2 3 4 5 thats what is says in the file

Comment: are they in seperate line?

Comment: I don't think that's really the same code that gives that error

Comment: @Whitefret no, `for line in d` is valid method of iteration over file lines

Comment: @Whitefret there all in the same line the file reads 1 2 3 4 5 1 2

Comment: yeah that is the problem, see @Lafexlos post for solution

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to convert whole string to integer.

First split that string, then cast integer on each item.

```
with open('Position_of_Words.txt') as d:    #my file 
    for line in d:
        if line: #checks if line is not empty    
            position_of_words_list = list(map(int, line.split())) 
            print (position_of_words_list)

#since there is only one line in txt file, you can also use something like below
with open("input.txt","r") as f:
    position_of_words_list  = list(map(int, f.read().split()))
    print position_of_words_list
```

Since you have only one line, above should work. If there are more than one line, you can append each line into the list.

```
position_of_words_list = [] #which will be list of lists
with open('Position_of_Words.txt') as d:    #my file 
    for line in d:
        if line: #checks if line is not empty    
            position_of_words_list.append(list(map(int, line.split())))
    print (position_of_words_list)
```

Comment: it doesn't work it displays <map object at 0x1033b1908>

Comment: @AshJaimal Then you should cast list on that as well. Edited.

Comment: thanks but when printing there is a double square bracket? [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2]]

Comment: @AshJaimal You should use first one if your text is one-lin and that should only print one set of brackets.

Comment: Good answer, upvoted. You could also use a list comprehension instead of map(): `output = [int(i) for i in line.split()]`

Comment: THANK YOU very much i appreciate it!!

Comment: @Lafexlos Add a try except for non-numeric input. Raise `zero`!

Answer (score 1):

Since the file has only one line and the line read as string you are getting that error.

```
with open('t.txt','r') as d:
    for line in d:
        position_of_words_list = [int(i) for i in line.split(' ')]
    print position_of_words_list
```

Comment: yeah in the file it goes 1 2 3 4 5 1 2

Comment: Please, add this as a comment, it's not an answer.

Comment: @JeanJung I believe being able to comment on other people's posts (answers/questions) is only enabled when you have 50 reputation. So anyone down voting is really just making the problem worse.

Comment: @Dunes I don't downvoted the answer, I was just trying to help him, sorry I forgot that there is reputation needed to create comments.

Comment: @JeanJung I wasn't casting blame on you. In fact your response is almost ideal -- you're trying to help Suresh out. It's just that Suresh can't do what you've recommended yet.

Comment: @SureshJ: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​As Laur linked to [the Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead), you should **never post a comment as an answer**. However, your edit makes this answer become a *real answer*. So that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is error in formatting the code, but the line variable is not inside the for block.

Also, if you have spaces in the lines you cannot convert it into int. It will only work if the line is a string with numbers only (no letter or any other special char like spaces).

Concerning the error itself, it looks like the iterator is converting the line into a list (probably of bytes?). Try to use str(line).

Comment: So you have a line with several numbers separated by spaces, correct? and you want to iterate over each and print them?